# Mirror a Microsoft Access 2007 file as a SQL database?

Tags: microsoft-access, sql, mirroring

We have a Microsoft Access 2007 database that we would like to *mirror* as SQL database (typically MSSQL or MySQL, but we are flexible here). The *mirrored* database is only used for read-only purposes. However, the mirror should be kept relatively up-to-date.

Is there any fully automated way to achieve this mirroring? (commercial tools would be OK too)

Comment: What is your actual scenario? What purpose is that SQL Server "mirror" of your A2007 database going to serve?

Comment: Scenario: legacy ERP based on Access holding sales data. Online sales data mirroring to enable Lokad.com to remotely grab the sales and offer web-based sales forecasts (dislaimer: I am working at Lokad.com).

Comment: Is the ACCDB/MDB file locally accessible ot the SQL Server? If so, why not mount it as a linked server, and the it will look like it's just SQL Server.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ACCDB/MDB file is NOT locally accessible from the SQL Server.